# matching either nothing (beginning of string) or any character but a \

Tags: php, regex, pcre

To use a simplified example, I have:

```
$str = "Hello :special_text:! Look, I can write \:special_text:";
$pattern = /*???*/":special_text:";
$res = preg_replace($pattern, 'world', $str);
$res = str_replace("/:", ":", $res);
$res === "Hello world! Look, I can write :special_text:"; // => true
```

In other words, I'd like to be able to "escape" something that I'm writing.

I think that I have something almost working (using `[^:]?` as the first part of pattern), but I don't think that works if `$str === ":special_text:", in that`^`doesn't match`[^:]?`.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what you're trying to do. Are you trying to write a regex that makes your initial `$str` string look like the end `$res` string?

Comment: I'm trying to fix `$pattern` so that the last line is true.

Comment: So you only want to replace `:special_text:` if it's not immediately preceded by a backslash?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. (Of course, it's really a more complex pattern but...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\\):special_text:
```

This says "replace a `:special_text:` that isn't preceded by a backslash".

In your second `str_replace` looks like you want to replace `\:` by `:`.

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?30006).

Also, don't forget if you use backslash in PHP strings you need to escape them once more (if you want a literal `\` you need to use PHP `\\`, and to get a literal `\\` you need to use PHP `\\\\`:

```
$pattern = '@(?<!\\\\):([^:]+):@';
```

Here the `@` is just a regex delimiter.

Comment: By the way: `preg_match('@(?<!\\):special_text:@', ''); // =>
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 20`

Comment: The `@` are the regex delimiters, like the `/my_regex/`. Sorry about the backslashes -- I thought you didn't have to escape them in single quotes for PHP but you do. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$pattern = "/[^\\\\]*:special_text:/";`

-or-

`$pattern = "/(?<!\\\\):special_text:/";`

The other answers don't take into account the need to super-escape the backslashes in this situation. It's a little crazy.

To match a literal backslash, one has to write `\\\\` as the regex string because the regular expression must be `\\`, and each backslash must be expressed as `\\` inside a string literal. In regexes that feature backslashes repeatedly, this leads to lots of repeated backslashes and makes the resulting strings difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it: `/[^\\]\:([a-z]+)\:/i`

You can use [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/) to text your regex against possible strings in realtime.

Comment: I don't think JavaScript and PECL regexes are fully compatible, especially with stuff like `/i`', but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You need to actually do `[^\\\\]` to avoid backslash craziness ... `[^\\]` won't cut it.

Comment: Got a link or explanation for that? As far as I'm aware, ` \\ ` escapes the backslash, which is fine.

Comment: Errr... Bluff ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_My_Bluff_(UK_game_show) ). One backslash escapes the next character, and if that next character is a backslash, it uses that as a string literal.

Comment: [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) (the boxed **Note:** near the top), and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) (the second paragraph under *The preg Function Set*.